# Ask new quesion in email, start a new email with subject or reply to old email thread?

Tags: email

I want to ask a new Question on email, but I don't know if I need to start a new email with subject, or ask a new question through replying to old email thread.

How to know which option to act?

Comment: Is it on the same subject?

Comment: And do a majority on the chain need to know the answer, or answer it, or be aware it was asked?

Comment: @Bernhard Döbler yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there is a right or a wrong in this, but the following would roughly be my reasoning:

1) Is it on a different project/subject? yes -> New email, no -> reply on thread

2) Is the information in the thread important for this question? yes -> reply on thread, no -> new email

In that order IMHO.